# Where does the Tiferes Yisroel discuss Edward Jenner and smallpox?

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, medicine, acharonim

I've heard repeatedly that the Tiferes Yisroel describes Dr. Edward Jenner as a righteous gentile for developing the smallpox inoculation -- where is that quote, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tiferet Yisrael (Boaz) on Avot 3:14 cited and translated [here](http://rabbisedley.blogspot.com/2012/08/tiferet-yisrael-jews-and-non-jews.html).

Comment: Original Hebrew [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&st=&pgnum=347&hilite=).

Comment: Thank you! It's on Hillel's comment that G-d loves all humans. What's the Yiddish word he's using for vaccinations, by the way? *Fakenimfung*?

Comment: @Shalom "Inoculation" in English translates as "Impfung" in German. Maybe the syllables פאקקענ stand for "vaccine"?

Comment: @Shalom, he is saying "the Pockenimpfung", which is German for [Smallpox vaccination](http://www.dict.cc/english-german/smallpox.html).

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, פאקקען is Pocken - smallpox in German.